# How can I use sklearn label encoder and apply to my dataframe directly

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I have a dataframe and I want to use LabelEncoder directly on it.

DataFrame:

```
df.select_dtypes('object').iloc[:,1:]

  Gender  Married x_y   x_z 
0   Male    No     0     No       
1   Male    Yes    1     No         
2   Male    Yes    2     Yes        
3   Male    Yes    3+    No   
4   Male    No     1     No
```

I tried these:

```
le = LabelEncoder()
df.select_dtypes('object').iloc[:,1:].apply(le.fit_transform, axis=1)
```

> TypeError: ("'<' not supported between instances of 'float' and
>   'str'", 'occurred at index 11')

```
df.select_dtypes('object').iloc[:,1:].apply(LabelEncoder.fit_transform)
```

> TypeError: ("fit_transform() missing 1 required positional argument:
>   'y'", 'occurred at index Gender')

Any help on how to use it.

Comment: For starters, `LabelEncoder()` is meant for a single column, your targets or category labels. Are you looking for `OneHotEncoder()`?

Comment: @G.Anderson I have seen multiple posts on So that you can use it via `apply` function.

Comment: I want to convert category labels to `o` or `1` based on category directly.

Comment: `df.apply(LabelEncoder().fit_transform)`, where `df` is the dataframe with all of the columns that you want transformed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `df` is your filtered dataframe that you want transformed (e.g. per your example in the question):

```
>>> df.apply(LabelEncoder().fit_transform)
   Gender  Married  x_y  x_z
0       0        0    0    0
1       0        1    1    0
2       0        1    2    1
3       0        1    3    0
4       0        0    1    0
```

To make it more general for decoding, you need to keep track of your label encoders (I used a dictionary keyed on the dataframe column names).  You then need to fit each one.

```
encoders = {col: LabelEncoder().fit(df[col]) for col in df}

encoded_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {col: encoders[col].transform(df[col]) for col in df},
    index=df.index)
>>>encoded_df
   Gender  Married  x_y  x_z
0       0        0    0    0
1       0        1    1    0
2       0        1    2    1
3       0        1    3    0
4       0        0    1    0

decoded_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {col: encoders[col].inverse_transform(encoded_df[col]) for col in encoded_df},
    index=encoded_df.index)
  Gender Married x_y  x_z
0   Male      No   0   No
1   Male     Yes   1   No
2   Male     Yes   2  Yes
3   Male     Yes  3+   No
4   Male      No   1   No
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to do the trick. Is it possible to convert them back?

Answer (score 0):

The most basic way I can think is to select the object columns, then loop through them and `fit_transform()` using the LabelEncoder

```
for col in df.select_dtypes(object).columns:
    df[col]=LabelEncoder().fit_transform(df[col])
```

Comment: Is it possible to achieve it via `apply` function?